# Why does this work on the Complex plane but not on $(-\infty,0]$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function

Suppose $e^{f(z)}=z$. Applying Log on both sides, $Log(e^{f(z)})=Log(z)$, so $log|e^{f(z)}|+i(\theta + 2\pi n)= Log(z)$, for $\theta$ between $-\pi$ and $pi$ and n integer. Now, $log|e^{f(z)}|+i\theta$ is the principal Log, so it is the inverse function of e, so it is simply $f(z)$. Therefore, $f(z) = Log (z) + 2i \pi n$ for n integer.

But I know this result only works for f(z) holomorphic on $\mathbb C $ \ $(-\infty, 0]$. Why? Which step requires this?

Answer (score 1):

It works even on the negative real axis, but $n$ depends on $z$. $n=n(z)$ is continuous (and therefore a constant) when you remove the negative real axis, but it is not continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.